# What is the distribution shape of the frequencies of a random uniform distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

Suppose $x$ is randomly sampled uniformly from $[0,N)$. Suppose we take $M$ samples. In my testing, I have been using $N=50000, M = 1000000$. The expected number of times each $i \in[0,N)$ was sampled is $M/N$. The shape of this distrubition is **uniform.**

However, suppose we took this random uniform distribution and counted, not the number of times $x$ was $0$, but the number of values which were sampled $0$ times. Let's call that the $\mathbf{freq}(0)$. We can get the $\mathbf{freq}(j)$ values for all $[0,M]$. This distrubution is **not uniform**. It looks kind of like a Poisson distrubution centered at $M/N$, but I'm not sure.

In case I wasn't totally clear, here is an example. Suppose we randomly sample uniformly from $[0,10)$ 54 times. The number of times each was sampled is a random uniform distribution looking something like $\{5, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4\}$, meaning that among the 54 samples, 0 was sampled 5 times, 1 was sampled 4 times, 2 was sampled 5 times, etc. But the distribution of these frequencies is $\{0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1,0, 0\dots\}$ since there is one value which was sampled three times, 3 values which were sampled four times, 4 values which were sampled five times, etc. What is the shape of this distribution?

Comment: Please feel welcome to clean up any of my terminology.

Comment: How do you define $\mathbf{freq}(3)$ if the random uniform distribution looks "something like" $\{\color{red}{3}, 4, 5, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 4\}$ i.e. $4$ and $5$ (were both drawn three times) ?

Comment: With a random uniform distribution of $\{3,4,5,5,6,4,3,5,6,7,4\}$ (meaning 0 was sampled three times, 1 was sampled four times, 2 was sampled five times, ... 9 was sampled four times), $\mathbf{freq}(3) = 2$ since two values were sampled 3 times each (0 was sampled three times, and 6 was sampled three times).

Comment: Essentially what I am asking is what is the distribution shape of the frequencies of the random uniform distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability that any fixed number in $[0, N)$ gets sampled once is $\frac{1}{N}$, so the distribution of the number of times it gets sampled in total is a binomial distribution $\text{Bin} \left( M, \frac{1}{N} \right)$. If $M, N$ are large and about the same size this approaches a Poisson distribution $\text{Pois} \left( \frac{M}{N} \right)$ by the [Poisson limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_limit_theorem). These Poisson distributions for different numbers in $[0, N)$ are, it turns out, also approximately independent, so we approximately get $N$ independent samples from this Poisson distribution.